# Parametrizing Union

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following tables

**TabA**

| Name | qty | batchNo | tabType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 200 | null | A |
| X | 200 | null | A |
| X | 100 | null | A |

**TabB**

| Name | qty | batchNo | tabType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 500 | null | B |
| Y | 50 | null | B |

I'm trying to get lines from Table B unless there are already lines for same name in Table A.
Problem seems easy, but I can't find elegant solution.

I'm trying to get

| Name | qty | batchNo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 200 | null |
| X | 200 | null |
| X | 100 | null |
| Y | 50 | null |

While I UNION ALL both tables I get

**Tabela Union**

| Name | qty | batchNo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 200 | null |
| X | 200 | null |
| X | 100 | null |
| X | 500 | null |
| Y | 50 | null |

I created (ugly) code looking like that

```
With UNI as
(Select * from TabA UNION ALL TabB)

Select * from UNI U
where
(EXISTS (Select 1 from UNI B where a.name=b.name and a.tabType<>b.tabType and NVL(a.batchNo)=NVL(b.batchNo)) and a.tabType ='A')
OR
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from a.name=b.name and a.tabType<>b.tabType)
```

Is there a way to parametrize UNION to make it look better?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> get lines from Table B unless there are already **lines for same name** in Table A.

If that's so, why are you checking other columns as well? If we stay with what question says, then - for

sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  taba (name, qty, batchno, tabtype) as
  3    (select 'x', 200, null, 'a' from dual union all
  4     select 'x', 200, null, 'a' from dual union all
  5     select 'x', 100, null, 'a' from dual
  6    ),
  7  tabb (name, qty, batchno, tabtype) as
  8    (select 'x', 500, null, 'b' from dual union all
  9     select 'y',  50, null, 'b' from dual
 10    )
```

Query looks like this:

```
 11  select b.* from tabb b where not exists (select null from taba a where a.name = b.name)
 12  union all
 13  select a.* from taba a where     exists (select null from tabb b where b.name = a.name);

NAME              QTY BATCHNO    TABTYPE
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
y                  50            b
x                 100            a
x                 200            a
x                 200            a

SQL>
```